# Set a param as required without defining it in the route in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, request

I have an action defined like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/doSomething/{someId}", name="do_something")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @ParamConverter("someId", class="MyBundle:Something")
 */
public function someAction(Something $something) {
    ...
}
```

I would like to use a token param, passed as a "normal" query string parameter, e.g.:

```
/myController/doSomething/5?token=2a47c2ff18a5d53cbaa5840b6c7c4008
```

What would be the proper way to make this parameter required and setting some requirements for it, like - for example - to match `^[\da-z]+$`? Is there a way to specify this in the annotation syntax?

One way I see it would be to do it manually, for example like this:

```
public function someAction(Something $something, Request $request) {
    $token = $request->query->get('token');
    $regexConstrain = new Regex('^[\da-z]+$');
    $regexConstrain->message = 'Invalid token';

    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($token, $regexConstrain);

    if (count($errors)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException($errors[0]->getMessage());
    }

    ...
}
```

But is there a faster, built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way ot if this way will be faster, but the [OptionsResolver](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) can handle such case, using the *Value Validation*.

As defined in [this french article](http://devblog.lexik.fr/tips/validation-des-parametres-passes-en-get-avec-l-optionsresolver-2336), you can use the OptionResolver to validate query parameter.

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

public function someAction(Something $something, Request $request)
{
    $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
    $resolver->setAllowedValues('token', function ($value) {
        return (bool) preg_match('/^[\da-z]+$/', $value);
    });

    // will throw a `Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException`
    // if token doesn't match the regex
    $resolver->resolve($request->query->all());

    ...
}
```